# Event prediction using Statistical or Black box approach

Tags: time-series, neural-networks, forecasting, predictive-models

I just came across a problem related to Event prediction in timeseries data.
[image]
So there is a timeseries data having timestamp and event occurred at that time, and I need to predict the next set of events maybe for few months or days. Now my question is how should I approach this problem, assuming that I am not even sure that event can be predicted for these sets of event data.

**Question - 1: How to identify whether we can predict the events for future timestamps.**
**Question - 2 : If event can be predicted then how? Which methods I should choose?** 
*Any blackbox/whitebox approach, deep-learning, statistical methods, any approach or ideas would be appreciated*

Also I'm new to this space, any kind of help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I would guess there is a finite number of possible outcomes. So the starting model, with no temporal correlation could be something like:

$$
X \sim Categorical(\{\pi_{i=1\dots N}\})
$$

I.e. state of your system at any point is random. You can start by determining the probabilities of different states under such assumptions. Where you have $N$ categories and $\pi)$ are the probabilities of these events.

Next, you could look into something like [Markov Chain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain). Where there are finite number of outcomes, but probabilities of transitioning between different outcomes are now non-trivial, and depend on the initial state. Before diving any deeper it might be good to check just how far your results are from Markov Chain, i.e. just how much of the next state depends *only* on the previous step, and no steps before that. You may find that it suffices, especially if you allow complex outcomes. If nothing else, this will give you a good baseline, if it suffices then you will have a quite robust modelling framework with all the asymptotic results already known for Markov Chains.

After this you can try more complex models, but I would probably seek for choice of these models to be motivated by why Markov Chain does not fit the data.

Comment: just how much of the next state depends only on the previous step, and no steps before that - Is there any method to compute this? because this is also possible that one data depends upon last 10days but other data can depend upon last 15days?
Also it is possible that data is imbalanced ie one event is coming 75% then in these cases Markov chain will just return that event which has 75% occurences in past

Comment: Also Markov chain is not going to give the timestamp, when the predicted event is going to occur

Comment: @Raj, your questions suggest to me you are looking for plug-and-play solution, whereas I was suggesting ideas of how you could explore this. For plug and play you might be better off asking in a more tech forum, like main SE.

Comment: Regarding testing whether steps depend on just previous step or not. You can compute conditional likelihoods and check for correlation between step 0 and 2 given a fixed steps 1 etc. For next time-stamp, you can approach this as a Poisson-type process where the modeled quantity is rate of events, which will allow to estimate the time to next event.